# Disable HTTP service on Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have simple Spring Boot Gradle application below that does not takes any requests from web server. In case I run this application with simple gradle command or from inside Eclipse IDE it finishes. In case I run this application from Intellij IDEA it just stops at the end and not finishes. At the same time web service started on port 8080 which shows `Whitelabel Error Page`.

Why web service is started at all? Can I disable it? Can I change HTTP port? Why it is not started from Eclipse?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class runMe {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        System.out.println("starting");
        SpringApplication.run(runMe.class, args);
        System.out.println("ending");

    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> 
        {

            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println("Name "+beanName);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

UPD

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-web` or `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` similar in project dependencies?

Comment: Please post your  build.gradle file.

Comment: Yes , I have `spring-boot-starter-web` in dependencies. Whole content of `build.gradle` in UPD in question body.